# smartgwt Window addmember padding

Tags: smartgwt, listgrid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SmartGWT Dialog title not set correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405204/smartgwt-dialog-title-not-set-correctly)

I have a problem, is that I have a Listgrid already formed but when I add it to a window with the method addMember the window controls including the title, go to the bottom, do not want that, I tried to put a padding to the window but does not work .. any ideas? here my code:

```
final Window winModal = Utils.createModalWindow("Title", true, true, true);
winModal.addCloseClickHandler(new CloseClickHandler() {
public void onCloseClick(CloseClientEvent event) {
winModal.destroy();
}
});
winModal.setPadding(1000);
winModal.setAlign(VerticalAlignment.CENTER);
winModal.setContentLayout("vertical");
winModal.addMember(getListGrid(), Integer.MAX_VALUE);
winModal.show();
```

thanks a lot.

Note: The Method getListGrid returns the listgrid component already formed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addItem` is the correct way of adding items in the `Window`

Check the `Javadoc` : http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/Window.html

Comment: you're absolutely right .... many thanks for the help: D! greetings.